# get bundle products that a common product belongs to Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9

Guys I'm needing to get all the packaged products that a simple product belongs to, in magento 1. How could I do that? I tried to use a code but it doesn't work it simply returns an empty array.

edit:  getParentIdsByChild - is returning an empty array

```
 $bundleIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('bundle/selection')
        ->getParentIdsByChild($childId);
```

Answer (score 0):

I was working on similar feature.
Are you sure you have correct productId as $childId?

Tested on 1.9.4.5:

```
$bundleIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('bundle/selection')
                    ->getParentIdsByChild($_product->getId());

var_dump($bundleIds);
```

Result is:

```
array(2) { [0]=> string(5) "20084" [1]=> string(5) "20085" }
```

Those IDs are bundles including simple product (which is $_product->getId() ).
Have you tried reindexing and try enabling / disabling flat tables for testing.

My whole code for getting bundle products of current simple products (for now) is:

```
        $bundleIds = Mage::getResourceSingleton('bundle/selection')
            ->getParentIdsByChild($_product->getId());
        //var_dump($bundleIds);

        foreach($bundleIds as $productId){
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId); //consider caching as this load whole product!
            $bundleCollectionOptions = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSelectionsCollection(
                $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getOptionsIds($product), $product
            );
            foreach($bundleCollectionOptions as $option) {
                echo '<pre>';
                print_r($option);
                echo '</pre>';
            }
        }
```